# Request Tracker 4.2.8 migrate database from sqlite to mysql

Tags: mysql, sqlite, rt

I am having a hard time migrating Request Tracker 4.2.8 database from sqlite to mysql.

I've tried the following:
http://technolengy.com/articles/rt4-sqlite-woes/

It migrates most of the data, but doesn't migrate Tickets Links (I can't figure out why - i checked and added all the tables) and also it changes the order of some config values in Admin/Tools/System Configuration.

Comment: I've also tried this solution: http://shadow.cat/blog/ian-norton/2013/January/request-tracker-4-assumptions/  . Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RT has serializer and importer tools that can help when switching databases. The [rt-serializer](https://docs.bestpractical.com/rt/4.2.13/rt-serializer.html) program writes out your database to disk in a format that can be read by the companion [rt-importer](https://docs.bestpractical.com/rt/4.2.13/rt-importer.html) program. There are many different options because people use these tools for different use cases, so read through them to see what might apply.

Comment: Thanks! I ran the following:
rt-serializer --clone
rt-setup-database --action create,schema,acl --dba root --prompt-for-dba-password
rt-importer {filename}

Everything was imported except the Ticket Links (I'm not sure why, maybe I had a bug on sqlite or something).

Comment: Could be. You can try running rt-validator on your original DB and it might tell you if something isn't quite right with your links or configuration.

Comment: Thank You! I used rt-validator --check --verbose --resolve and after that all the data was imported.